# Is it possible to create strongly typed web.config references?

Tags: .net, configuration

Is it possible to create strongly typed references in a web.config or app.config so that the build will break when those type references haven't been added to the project?

For example, say I have a WhizzBangerFactory which looks in the web.config for declared WhizzBangers. I might have configuration like,

```
<whizBangs>
<add name="SuperDooper" type="MyProject.WhizzBangers.SuperDooperWhizzBanger, MyProject.WhizzBangers" />
<add name="Fantastical" type="AnotherProject.WhizzBangers.FantasticalWhizzBanger, AnotherProject.WhizzBangers" />
</whizBangs>
```

This will compile perfectly fine even if there are no references to MyProject.WhizzBangers andAnotherProject.WhizzBangers. What I would like is for the build to fail and inform me that I've missed the references.

Comment: I wonder if this can achieved with tools such as Resharper?

Comment: Create an executable that checks what you need by parsing your .config file or another way. Call this executable from Pre-build event.

Answer (score 3):

The web.config is runtime only resolution. To late for build success or failure.

If the same build builds the types that are referenced in the web.config, parse the web.config file to verify that all the files exist ( this would require that all the needed binaries for the web site end up in a common directory. For something like tfs this would be done as a post compile step and only on success are the binaries copied to the drop directory otherwise the build is failed

If the other types are provided by another build and included as part of an installer the same sort of config file parsing could be run as a standalone app ( part of the install ) as a sanity check

The other way ( would be to include another project in your build that references all the types you might need, create an instance of the type so that the compiler does not optimize away ) and add this project as a dependency of your web project. That way if the type project fails then web build project fails as well

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - as Rafa suggests perhaps a better idea is to just not use web.config to solve the problem and look at other solutions such as IOC.

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

Firsly, how does your project compile even if the references are missing? That implies you don't really need them! How can you have a strongly typed reference to something you don't need? You're asking to be warned when you have missed off an *unnecessary* reference?

Secondly,

I'm still not clear on exactly what you want to do, but I think what you want can be achieved by creating a pre-build step. You might have to write a little C# console program to do the processing and checking of the web.config file.

It is similar to the way that Visual Studio generates a class to represent your resources or properties if you add them using the tooling. For example, if you go to Project -> Properties, Resources tab, then create a resource, you will find that Visual Studio will spit out a Resources.Designer.cs file with a class in that you can then refer to in your code as

```
Properties.Resources.MyTestResource
```

Interestingly, inside the generated code is this comment

```
/// <summary>
///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
/// </summary>
// This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
// class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
// To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
// with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
```

It sounds like you might be able to do something similar in your project, perhaps by adding a pre-build step that generates the class for you?

The StronglyTypedResourceBuilder class has a reference page here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.tools.stronglytypedresourcebuilder.aspx

Looks reasonably easy to use. This may not be applicable in your scenario though, I am just using it as an example. It sounds more like you want to generate a proxy type or something...

Answer (score 1):

Resharper can help you with this.

It visually distinguishes things in a web.config where the type is not referenced (or you've made a mistake - in this example I took a "t" off the end of "Microsoft")

[image]

However, it still doesnt fail to compile, which is a shame. It should!

Comment: But that's the point rue sharper can't be used to fail am automated build

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you as alternative to use some kind of IoC system. Microsoft already offers the Unity Framework, it will work better than this solution that you are trying. Ninject is also quite good.

http://www.ninject.org/

Comment: I think that may be the best idea, I guess if it's not possible to get compile time errors out of the web.config for missing types then a different solution would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Philip Daniels said, you might need a post-build step.

Let the project compile so that it can place all the referenced DLLs in its output folder and then have a tool (probably custom written or maybe if there is something on Github or Codeplex) scan the .config file and see if the specified type can be found in the output folder.

If it can't be found, then the tool returns a non-zero return code to indicate to the build process (just make sure it hooks into the build process, you would have to let the ms-project build event capture that error code manually, I think) that it failed with an appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make an Msbuild step by either creating a [new Task implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx), or by using the [Inline Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx) , which parses the class names from your web.config and attempts to load them using [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx). If loading fails it will throw an exception which will fail your build.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try writing an Unit Test which will use this configuration and integrate the test as part of the build? This will give the correct indicator that some tests are failing even in an automated build system and help you catch the issue.

Or you can try placing the whizBangs configuration in a separate configuration file and mention the source in web.config. When this separate configuration file is saved, you can invoke a customtool(facility for custom tool already available in VS) which will autogenerate a cs file forming the class representation of the config file. This cs file can be checked-in with appropriate comments generated by the custom tool indicating its purpose. Whenever a developer changes this file and saves, both config and cs files will be checked out and edited.